# How to stop " point " to be replaced by a " comma" in the output of a VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

Initially it is important to note that I use MS Excel in **Brazilian Portuguese**.

That's my code:

```
Dim C1 As Integer
Dim C2 As Integer
Dim Cod As String

C1 = Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("D1").Value
C2 = Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("D2").Value

Cod = C1 & "." & C2

Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("D3").Value = Cod
```

> Cells:
>
> D1 = 1
>
> D2 = 2

I expected that the output would be "1.2", but it's "1,2"!

What am I doing wrong?

And I apologize for my rusty English

Thank you!

Comment: try cdbl(C1 & "." & C2) ?

Comment: Does the value `1.2` need to be interpreted as a numeric value by the worksheet? If that's the case, the comma is irrelevant.

Comment: Edit Regional Settings in Windows and alter separator character if it's OK for you to make it work like that globally in your system. Otherwise alter the column/cell number format ("more number formats..." option or "special" if nothing else works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this before outputting the value to the range:

```
Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("D3").NumberFormat = "@"
```

This changes the format of the cell to Text which prevents Excel to interpret the value you write to it as a number.

Comment: Alternatively you can also precede the string with an apostrophe (which has the same effect): `Worksheets("Dictionary").Range("D3").Value = "'" & Cod`

Comment: @RafaelSTK I suppose your next SO question will be asking why your text-formatted values aren't treated as numbers and mess up your formulas. The real answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37119843/1188513)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the tip! I am using this data as an " index " . If I needed this data to calculate I really need to change as MS Excel understands the "point " .

Answer (score 1):

You use your Excel in "Brazilian Portuguese". The change may be due to the International Settings in the Windows Control Panel.

If your International Settings define the "," as the decimal separator, then Excel will convert the dot to the comma when you make the assignment in Visual Basic. This behavior makes the VBA code independent of locale settings and so makes the code portable in the international context (I assume that is the intention of this behavior).

If Brazilian Portuguese needs the dot as separator, <strike>then set your computer to use the dot as decimal separator, however, it shouldn't matter because</strike> when you send the spreadsheet to Brazil, the Excel there will use the correct decimal separator (I assume numbers are stored as binary floating point so dot or comma is only a matter of presentation).

EDIT: strikethrough of text above that would seem a workaround, as setting the international seting/decimal separator makes no difference for the end result.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Forcing the dot by formatting the cell as text will change the way Excel interprets the value (e.g. text vs. number), which can (will) break any/all worksheet calculations relying on that value.

Comment: Although it is true that the dot or comma is just a matter of presentation, writing *to* a cell in Excel causes it to be interpreted based on the locale settings (think of it as a "reverse presentation"). This benefits non-technical users who want to enter floats with their locale decimal separator. But it makes entering numbers via VBA with a fixed decimal separator a game of chance, only working if it matches the locale decimal separator (which, in the OP's case, it doesn't). Locale settings therefore do the exact opposite as you wrote: they make code *dependent* of the locale settings.

Comment: @Mat's Mug: That was the intention of the OP - why would they otherwise complain about the different output? It's all about writing a number to a cell *without* it being interpreted as a number. At least that's how I understood the question. Furthermore, changing the locale settings is a nasty workaround that has a huge impact on a lot of other applications relying on these settings. And it's not portable: You'll have the same problem at each machine that you run the VBA code on. Been there, done that. Never doing it again. Always write your code being independent of locale settings.

Comment: @Leviathan then you're a good mind-reader, because the OP never specified that their numeric values should be treated as text.

Comment: @Mat's Mug: Well, it strongly reminded me of problems I had myself. You probably never experienced those because you're lucky to have the same decimal comma where you live as the one that is used in programming languages.
But you have a point, it could also be the other way round. Let's see if your prophecy (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119018/how-to-stop-point-to-be-replaced-by-a-comma-in-the-output-of-a-vba-code/37119843#comment61782193_37119370) comes true. :)

Comment: @Leviathan: "_entering numbers via VBA with a fixed decimal separator a game of chance_" is NOT true. I ran a test and it behaves exactly as I said: in VBA always use dot; in Excel the international settings determine presentation and input in cells.

Comment: @Paul you are right, I messed that part up. Locale settings only affect string-to-number conversion and vice versa. What I said applies to that and still holds true. Writing to an Excel cell using VBA, however, is a different matter. Locale settings *are* ignored here. That makes *this* part of VBA really locale independent. Other parts, however - as indicated above - will still work differently (or sometimes: work *not at all*) with differing locale settings.

Comment: @Leviathan, the behavior of string-to-number/date conversion in VBA is consistent with locale settings. I think that is proper. However, in Word I found the behavior with International setings work very badly. In Word the locale should be set in the document, not by the local computer's setting (think about Word's decimal tab...)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Replace()

    Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = "=SUBSTITUTE(A1,""."","","")"

End Sub
```

You can change your range accordingly.

Example -  Range("B1:B3").Value = "=SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,""."","","")"

Comment: See [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use Markdown to format your posts on Stack Exchange. FWIW `Range` all by itself is an implicit reference to the active sheet, and `Select`/`Activate` should be avoided (I've edited it out of your original answer); also this answer doesn't address the source of the problem, and may alter the way Excel understands the numeric value `1.2`, which is presumably not what the OP is trying to achieve.